# Basic authentication in subdir breaks RewriteRules of parent dir?

Tags: .htaccess, authentication, mod-rewrite

In /public_html/.htaccess, I've got rewrite rules as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^(subdir1)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(subdir2)($|/) - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www.example.com/$1 [L]
```

So, if a visitor goes to the url http://www.example.com/subdir1 (or subdir2), it will serve up the files from /public_html/subdir1 (or subdir2).  Otherwise, it will 'default' to the files in /public_html/www.example.com.  This works as intended.

However, if I place an .htaccess & associated .htpasswd file in /public_html/subdir1:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Private"
AuthUserFile "/public_html/subdir1/.htpasswd"
require valid-user
```

...the RewriteRules suddenly break.  Visiting http://www.example.com/subdir1 no longer serves up files from subdir1, instead returning a 404 from the CMS located in public_html/www.example.com/.

What gives?  Why would adding a password to subdir break the parent's rewriterules?

Comment: Do you have _anything else_ in `/public_html/subdir1/.htaccess`?

Comment: The path to your .htpasswd file would seem to be invalid? This _should be_ an absolute file system path.

Comment: 1) Nothing else in .htaccess - just those four lines.  2) The path is absolute, & valid (the actual path I listed above was just an example - my htaccess actually lists /home/(my_username)/public_html/subdir1/.htpasswd.  Apologies for being unclear, I was just abbreviating.

Comment: Check the error log and add any relevant entries to your post. Also how are you mapping request to your CMS, Via a rewrite, a `ProxyPass`, or is it just an app located in `/public_html/www.example.com/` or something else?

Comment: Since it's shared hosting, I unfortunately don't have access to the raw server error logs.  The CMS is a Wordpress installation whose files are located in public_html/www.example.com.